# gcc compilation of C file: error in mainCRTStartup

Tags: java, c, gcc

I'm trying to compile a 27KB .c file in Powershell (Windows 10) using java and the TDM-GCC MinGW provided on sourceforge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/).  The code I am using (from published paper http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1001059) generates an executable file using the following code:

```
gcc -O3 -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -fno-strict-aliasing --param max-inline-insns-single=1800 -std=c99 -msse2 -DHAVE_SSE2 -DDSFMT_MEXP=521 -o toy_bat toy_bat.c
```

When I compile a 6KB example file this works fine.  However when I compile the 27KB file I get the following error:

C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/.../lib/crt2.o: In function '__tmainCRTStartup' followed by a load of 'relocation truncated to fit' messages.

From what I've read onling this error normally comes from a file being too large, but I find it hard to believe that A 27KB file is causing this.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what may be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest trying a different compiler first (e.g. Cygwin); I'm not familiar with that TDM one, and it's almost a year old. Also try adding -m64 to make sure you're getting a 64-bit binary. You could also try some live compiler site like ideone.com to see if it works with some gcc versions but not others.

Comment: The actual size might be much larger as I see the compilation line is explicitly asking to attempt inlining of *all* of the functions  while increasing the size limit for the inline functions 3 times more than the default. Try removing `-finline-functions`

Comment: Does it compile without the `-finline-functions` option?

Comment: Is the 'java' tag relevant to this question? You mentioned java, but it seems to be about compiling C code.

Comment: @Zastai Thanks, I've installed MinGW and that's identified the error more specifically: "int C3bSctr [100] [50]..." Is too large!

Comment: @EugeneSh. You're right, I now get the error message in my above reply to Zastai. Unfortunately I got the same error when removing -finline-functions, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the *full* error message?

Comment: @EugeneSh This is the full message: toy_bat.c:50:5: error: size of array 'C3bSctr' is too large int C3bSctr [100] [50] [50] [50] [50] [50] [50] [50] [50] [50] [50] [50] ;

Comment: wat? `100*50^11` ints? Are you serious? do you have some kind of alien technology memory device?

Comment: And that is why you're supposed to post code - if I'd seen that array the problem would have been obvious. Very few machines will have several exabytes of storage available on the stack - even turning it into a heap-based allocation won't help.

Comment: The toy_bat.c that comes with the code linked from the article does not in fact contain such an array. It looks like you added zeroes turning 5 into 50 for no obvious reason (and without mentioning it in your post).